# Access 2010 conditional selection in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to complete my university coursework but i'm stuck with the selection process in a query.

Running Access 2010, I have to select the following fields:
Asset ID, Asset Description, Problem ID, Current Helpdesk person allocated to the problem or the date solved and the solution given.

How can I do a conditional select so that basically like it says, IF solution date is filled in, fetch the date and description. Otherwize, fetch the Helpdesk person who is assigned.

Please assume that all fields are in the Problems table and I can adapt from there as needed, just need a heads up on how to select a column in one case and if the case resolves to false, select an alternative column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not much idea about MS Access, but you can try it with IIF() function like below as MS Access doesn't support CASE WHEN clause. You can also use Format() function to convert date in string with whatever format you want.

```
SELECT Asset_ID, 
       Asset_Description, 
       Problem_ID
       IIF(IsNull(Date), Helpdesk_Person, CStr(Date) + Description) as Solution
FROM Problems
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks.